# Openldap Replication Problems with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, replication, openldap

I want to make a replication from openldap.

My config files are below, but did I miss something?

The first one is running on the Primary Server and the second one is on the Replication Server.

Ubuntu Server is Version 17.10 and all Updates are installed.

To edit the Domain I use phpldapadmin.

```
#provider_sync.ldif
# Add indexes to the frontend db.
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryCSN eq
-
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq

#Load the syncprov and accesslog modules.
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: syncprov
-
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: accesslog

# Accesslog database definitions
dn: olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/accesslog
olcSuffix: cn=accesslog
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=ch
olcDbIndex: default eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN,objectClass,reqEnd,reqResult,reqStart

# Accesslog db syncprov.
dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: syncprov
olcSpNoPresent: TRUE
olcSpReloadHint: TRUE

# syncrepl Provider for primary db
dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: syncprov
olcSpNoPresent: TRUE

# accesslog overlay definitions for primary db
dn: olcOverlay=accesslog,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAccessLogConfig
olcOverlay: accesslog
olcAccessLogDB: cn=accesslog
olcAccessLogOps: writes
olcAccessLogSuccess: TRUE
# scan the accesslog DB every day, and purge entries older than 7 days
olcAccessLogPurge: 07+00:00 01+00:00
```

Replication Server Config

```
#consumer_sync.ldif
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: syncprov

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
-
add: olcSyncRepl
olcSyncRepl: rid=0 provider=ldap://172.16.116.156 bindmethod=simple binddn="cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=ch"
  credentials=SECTRET searchbase="dc=domain,dc=ch" logbase="cn=accesslog"
  logfilter="(&(objectClass=auditWriteObject)(reqResult=0))" schemachecking=on
  type=refreshAndPersist retry="60 +" syncdata=accesslog
-
add: olcUpdateRef
olcUpdateRef: ldap://172.16.116.156
```

Comment: Why would you replicate the access log? And nothing else? And what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I want to replicate the complete OpenLDAP. The second Ldap Server don't get any data.

Comment: But the slave has its *own* access log. You don't want to replicate the master's access log into the slave on top of its own log. You want to replicate its DIT. Try that.